# Date Compare 2 files - see if a file needs updating

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I'm wanting to update a file if a file in a central folder is newer.

Here's what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work as the months change - works OK for days and minutes.

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#baseViewStackDir#" filter="#viewStackFileName#" name="base_fileInfo">
<!--- end --->
<cfset myViewStackDir = ExpandPath('/designer/app') />
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#myViewStackDir#" filter="#viewStackFileName#" name="target_fileInfo">
<cfset copy = false />
<cfif DateCompare(base_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,target_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,"yyyy") GT 0 >
  <cfset copy = true />
<cfelseif DateCompare(base_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,target_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,"m") GT 0>
  <cfset copy = true />
<cfelseif DateCompare(base_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,target_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,"d") GT 0>
  <cfset copy = true />
<cfelseif DateCompare(base_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,target_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,"h") GT 0>
  <cfset copy = true />
<cfelseif DateCompare(base_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,target_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,"n") GT 0>
  <cfset copy = true />
<cfelseif DateCompare(base_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,target_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,"s") GT 0>
  <cfset copy = true />
</cfif>
<cfif copy EQ true>
  <cffile action="copy" source="#baseViewStackDir##viewStackFileName#" destination="#myViewStackDir#"/>
</cfif>
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log("swf updated=<cfoutput>#copy# #base_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED# - #target_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED# ....#DateCompare(base_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,target_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,'m')#</cfoutput>");
</script>
```

Please can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: Why not just check if the two dates are not equal?

Comment: Yep, `<cfif base_fileInfo.DateLastModified GT target_fileInfo.DateLastModified >` = problem solved

Comment: BTW, if you were going to use `DateCompare`, you would only need a single comparison:  `<cfif DateCompare(date1, date2, "s") gt 1>`.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter and I alluded to in our comments you can change your entire script to be just this

```
<cfif base_fileInfo.DateLastModified GT target_fileInfo.DateLastModified>
  <cffile action="copy" source="#baseViewStackDir##viewStackFileName#" destination="#myViewStackDir#"/>
</cfif>

<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("swf updated=<cfoutput>#copy# #base_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED# - #target_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED# ....#DateCompare(base_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,target_fileInfo.DATELASTMODIFIED,'m')#</cfoutput>");
</script>
```

If you're trying to *autoversion* your js/css files you can use something like this to read the modified date of the file and append that date to the js/css url

```
<cffunction Name="autoversion" access="public" returntype="string" output="false">
  <cfargument Name="filepath" type="string" required="yes">
  <cfset var fileDate = createObject("java","java.util.Date").init(createObject("java","java.io.File").init('C:\railo\webapps\railo\website\bootstrap\js'&Replace(arguments.filepath, '/', '\', 'ALL')).lastModified())>
  <cfreturn 'https://www.mydomain.com/'&arguments.filepath&'?d='&DateFormat(fileDate, 'mmddyyyy')&TimeFormat(fileDate, 'hh')>
</cffunction>

<cfset autoversion('/bootstrap.js')>
```

Comment: You can also use [`getFileInfo()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d02.html) to get the date, instead of java objects.

Comment: That is an option, Leigh, but I've found it's 3-4x slower than using java objects

Comment: I am surprised at that, given the extra cost of java objects due to reflection. Plus with a single call or two, differences usually are not measurable. But you have got me curious. Let me run a few tests.

Comment: For 10,000 iterations the java object method takes 861ms and `getFileInfo()` takes 2273ms. Now for one call you'll never notice the difference, but if it's really a js/css versioner you will have a lot of calls going on for it.

Comment: (Edit) Yeah, it is slower for me too: 313 vs 1066. Probably a combination of permission checks and gathering extra file properties in getFileInfo. If you really were calling it thousands of times, the java route is faster. Otherwise, I would stick with the CF function.

Comment: Thank Matt, this simple way was the way I tried it first time but it wasn't reliable as we changed months.  I'm going with GetFileInfo for now

Comment: @DavidJennings how was it not reliable when months changed? If the base date is greater than the target date it'd be flagged whether it was 1 second difference, 1 month or 10 years.